# How could configure or modify SWFAddress to make it use #! instead of #

Tags: ajax, flash, seo, indexing, swfaddress

SWFAddress it's very cool way of providing deep linking in flash. But unless you use #! in urls (and a other things too), google wont index your internal pages.

How would be the best way to configure (or modify) SWFAddress to use #!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the answer in another question here in stackoverflow. I want to post the solution for future reference:

Just open swfaddress.js with your editor and replace all instances of "#" (with quotes), with "#!". Is that simple :)